# Let $f(x)=2\arccos x+4\operatorname{ arccot } x-3x^2-2x+10, x\in[-1,1]$. If $[a,b]$ is the range of $f(x)$, find $4a-b$.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, trigonometry, inverse-function

**Question:**

Let $f(x)=2\arccos x+4\operatorname{ arccot } x-3x^2-2x+10, x\in[-1,1]$. If $[a,b]$ is the range of $f(x)$, find $4a-b$.

**Method $1:$**

$f'(x)=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac{4}{1+x^2}-6x-2$

1st, 2nd and 4th terms are always negative. But not 3rd. Thus, can we say $f'(x)$ is negative?

**Method $2:$**

$\arccos x, \operatorname{ arccot } x, -2x$ are always decreasing. But not $-3x^2$. Thus, can we say $f(x)$ is decreasing?

Comment: How to write \arccot?

Comment: Put a space before the $x$ so that MathJax doesn't think it's "arccotx"

Comment: @B.Goddard I have already added space there

Comment: I see.  I edited with \mbox so you can see.

Comment: use "\:\:" command

Comment: @B.Goddard thankyou, noted for future

Comment: The correct command is `\operatorname{arccot}`, according to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146913

Comment: Note that domain of x is [-1,1].

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{arccot} x$ is decreasing, but it has a discontinuity at $0$

Comment: @Andrei $\operatorname{arccot}$ is a continuous function?

Comment: @insipidintegrator I have kept the domain in mind

Comment: @aarbee See [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcCot.html) for example

Comment: @Andrei [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), it's showing continuous

Comment: https://www.cuemath.com/arccot-formula/

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that is required to be found in the domain of the function which is $[-1,1]$ as we have to satisfy the domain of $\arccos(x)$
That done, we proceed to find the derivative,
$$f′()=−\frac2{\sqrt{1−^2}}-\frac4{1+x^2} -6x-2$$
when $x$ is between $0$ and $1$, the derivative is negative indicating a decreasing function in that portion. when $x$ is between $-1$ and $0$, we see that though the $-6x$ term is positive, it is still smaller in magnitude than the rest of the terms. (this you can confirm with any arbitrary value)
so the function is a decreasing function in its domain and it is also injective.
now all we have to do is find the values of $f(x)$ at $x=-1$ and $x=+1$ to get the range.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you

Comment: Hi. My confusion is especially regarding $f'(x)$ being negative. Thus, can you add any example in your answer?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. well, to judge about whether f'(x) is negative or not you could check the value of f'(x) at say x=-1/2 at which the derivative gives a value of about nearly -4.509. if you still aren't convinced, you can check out the graph of the function in demos where it stays below x-axis, quite conveniently and attains a maximum value of -2.965 at x=-0.815. hope that clears it. cheers